# Data crawled can be printed completely on the terminal, but cannot be completely written in text

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, web-crawler

I have crawled some data from the url, can it can be **perfectly shown on the terminal**.

### below is my code (crawling the movie name from a url):

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
import json

url= 'https://movie.douban.com/j/search_subjects?type=movie&tag=%E7%83%AD%E9%97%A8&page_limit=50&page_start=0'
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36',
'Referer':'https://www.baidu.com/link?url=WRKWuSkjVngibf0xz8JoiYzW3OIsrTP0-cj26aVvH8q7ZhP6qkOGY-Zwc8-HEGFw&wd=&eqid=9926e1c400630e7c000000035d90c4d7',
'Cookie': '_vwo_uuid_v2=D0DF3760AB53755DB79564FCF3EFA6601|fce72c403f87ac2ca7ae102837b10fec; __guid=223695111.4319207795202076000.1549549791840.3198; douban-fav-remind=1; viewed="27056409"; gr_user_id=8da42253-de1e-4f12-95ee-70a3cb0fda27; ll="118243"; bid=0SXwG9CmIhU; ap_v=0,6.0; _pk_ref.100001.4cf6=%5B%22%22%2C%22%22%2C1569768908%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.baidu.com%2Flink%3Furl%3DWRKWuSkjVngibf0xz8JoiYzW3OIsrTP0-cj26aVvH8q7ZhP6qkOGY-Zwc8-HEGFw%26wd%3D%26eqid%3D9926e1c400630e7c000000035d90c4d7%22%5D; _pk_ses.100001.4cf6=*; __utma=30149280.914565082.1523449990.1524056947.1569768908.3; __utmc=30149280; __utmz=30149280.1569768908.3.1.utmcsr=baidu|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic; __utma=223695111.2082725742.1523450059.1524056947.1569768908.3; __utmb=223695111.0.10.1569768908; __utmc=223695111; __utmz=223695111.1569768908.3.1.utmcsr=baidu|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic; UM_distinctid=16d7d84a6791f-00508116b3cea7-454c092b-100200-16d7d84a67a4c; CNZZDATA1272964020=1129763675-1569768675-https%253A%252F%252Fwww.baidu.com%252F%7C1569768675; __yadk_uid=RKbptYrIEyYDpE7KUTuHZW99Kmw5fxxz; __utmt_t1=1; _pk_id.100001.4cf6=bfdbd891f3d04fe0.1523450058.4.1569770601.1549549798.; __utmb=30149280.27.8.1569770601126; monitor_count=11; RT=s=1569770721069&r=https%3A%2F%2Fmovie.douban.com%2F'}

response=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html_str=response.content.decode()
html_dict=json.loads(response.content.decode())

movie_dict=html_dict['subjects']
for i in movie_dict:
    movie_name=i['title']
    movie_rate=i['rate']
    print (movie_name)
```

### below is the output (Movie name crawled and compeletely shown on the terminal):

```
银河补习班
保持沉默
我的天使
心理测量者SS2：第一卫士
心理测量者SS3
安娜
寄生虫
极限逃生
沉默的证人
仲夏夜惊魂
柳烈的音乐专辑
龙牌之谜
大侦探皮卡丘
友情以上
深夜食堂
送我上青云
蜘蛛侠：英雄远征
玩具总动员4
速度与激情：特别行动
流浪地球
疯狂的外星人
使徒行者2：谍影行动
烈火英雄
恶人传
无名之辈
飞驰人生
高草丛中
疾速备战
铤而走险
海王
阿丽塔：战斗天使
X战警：黑凤凰
蜘蛛侠：平行宇宙
我身体里的那个家伙
阿拉丁
巨鳄风暴
波西米亚狂想曲
白蛇：缘起
极限职业
亲密旅行
地久天长
复仇者联盟4：终局之战
鼠胆英雄
神奇动物：格林德沃之罪
骡子
小委托人
江南
爱宠大机密2
风中有朵雨做的云
无敌破坏王2：大闹互联网
```

But when I tried to write the data  into a text, it **only has 1 item in the text**

### below is the code of writing files in the text:

```
    with open('douban_movie.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(movie_name+'\n')
```

### below is the output of the code(only 1 item in the text):

```
无敌破坏王2：大闹互联网
```

## My question:

why is there only **1 item** written in the text while I have crawled **all the data**  and print them on the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why is there only 1 item written in the text while I have crawled all the data and print them on the terminal?

Because you probably have something like this

```
movie_dict=html_dict['subjects']
for i in movie_dict:
    movie_name=i['title']
    movie_rate=i['rate']
    print (movie_name)
    with open('douban_movie.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(movie_name+'\n')
```

when you most like should have

```
with open('douban_movie.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as file:
    movie_dict=html_dict['subjects']
    for i in movie_dict:
        movie_name=i['title']
        movie_rate=i['rate']
        print (movie_name)
        file.write(movie_name+'\n')
```

That is, open the file for writing once outside of the loop and then write to the file repeatedly within the loop.